# compilation error whith boost-python and lapack

Tags: c++, boost-python, lapack, lapacke

I created a program using boost for extracting python variables and lapack for solving matrix. However I have some trouble in compilation process

Here are my includes and the firsts line of code :

```
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
#include "lapacke.h"
#include <math.h>

#include <omp.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/times.h>

#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <limits>

#include <Python.h>
#include <arrayobject.h>

#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "boost/python/extract.hpp"


using namespace std;
```

The compilation results in a large amount of errors that I have difficulties to interpret this output. 
Here is a sample :

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/complex.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/lapacke.h:73,
                 from /project/git/CLCCD/whittaker/wfilter.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:308:26: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
 template <class T, class I, class R, class B = ::boost::detail::empty_base<T> >
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:308:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__extension__’
 template <class T, class I, class R, class B = ::boost::detail::empty_base<T> >
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:308:26: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘__extension__’
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:308:26: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
 template <class T, class I, class R, class B = ::boost::detail::empty_base<T> >
                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/chrono/detail/system.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/chrono/system_clocks.hpp:64,
                 from /usr/include/boost/chrono/chrono.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/timer/timer.hpp:14,
                 from /project/git/CLCCD/whittaker/wfilter.cpp:37:
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:649:7: error: ‘indexable’ was not declared in this scope
     , indexable<T, D, R, B
       ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:650:7: error: wrong number of template arguments (6, should be 3)
       > > > > {};
       ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:420:8: error: provided for ‘template<class T, class U, class B> struct boost::additive2’
 struct additive2
        ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:650:9: error: template argument 2 is invalid
       > > > > {};
         ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:650:11: error: template argument 3 is invalid
       > > > > {};
           ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:650:13: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘>’ token
       > > > > {};
             ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:650:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:851:1: error: ‘indexable’ is not a member of ‘boost’
 BOOST_OPERATOR_TEMPLATE3(indexable)
 ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:851:1: error: ‘indexable’ is not a member of ‘boost’
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:851:1: error: wrong number of template arguments (4, should be 1)
 BOOST_OPERATOR_TEMPLATE3(indexable)
 ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:731:26: error: provided for ‘template<class T> struct boost::is_chained_base’
 template<class T> struct is_chained_base {
                          ^
/usr/include/boost/operators.hpp:851:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘>’ token
 BOOST_OPERATOR_TEMPLATE3(indexable)
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/complex.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/lapacke.h:73,
                 from /project/git/CLCCD/whittaker/wfilter.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:34:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__extension__’
 template< int I > class spinlock_pool
               ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:34:15: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘__extension__’
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:34:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
 template< int I > class spinlock_pool
               ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:75:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__extension__’
 template< int I > spinlock spinlock_pool< I >::pool_[ 41 ] =
               ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:75:15: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘__extension__’
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:75:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
 template< int I > spinlock spinlock_pool< I >::pool_[ 41 ] =
               ^
 // some other lines ...
     In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/shared_ptr_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from /project/git/CLCCD/whittaker/wfilter.cpp:38:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: In function ‘boost::shared_ptr<T> boost::atomic_load(const boost::shared_ptr<T>*)’:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:954:5: error: ‘spinlock_pool’ is not a member of ‘boost::detail’
     boost::detail::spinlock_pool<2>::scoped_lock lock( p );
     ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:954:36: error: ‘::scoped_lock’ has not been declared
     boost::detail::spinlock_pool<2>::scoped_lock lock( p );
                                    ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: In function ‘void boost::atomic_store(boost::shared_ptr<T>*, boost::shared_ptr<T>)’:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:965:5: error: ‘spinlock_pool’ is not a member of ‘boost::detail’
     boost::detail::spinlock_pool<2>::scoped_lock lock( p );
     ^
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:965:36: error: ‘::scoped_lock’ has not been declared
     boost::detail::spinlock_pool<2>::scoped_lock lock( p );
                                    ^
// and it continues...
```

**Q :** My limited knowledge on compilation tends to suppose a conflict between lapack and boost, but how to resolve ?

**Q :** Is this a problem related to any namespace defined in cpp file ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact this was a problem in includes order...

by putting #include "lapacke.h" after boost includes, it solved the things...

I'm having other problems now... but that's another story...

Comment: Actually, `#include <boost/python.hpp>` MUST be your first include. See this : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/building/include_issues.html