# error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token }

Tags: c

I know this question was already asked, and I checked all the previous answers but still cannot find the error. The program is not finished yet so the logic is incomplete, I just want to run and check what I have so far.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int a[100][100];

int countNeighbors(int x, int y){

    int count = 0;
    int i,j;
    for (i = x-1; i <= x+1; i++)
        for (j = y-1; i <= y+1; j++)
            if (a[x][y] == 1) count++;

    return count;
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    int n, i, j, count;

    printf("Enter grid dimension:");
    scanf("%d",&n);   

// Initializing the array with random values
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            a[i][j] = rand() % 2;


    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < n-1; j++){
            count = countNeighbors(i,j);
            if (a[i][j] == 1){
                if (count >= 4 || count <=1) a[i][j] = 0;
                else a[i][j] = 1;
            }   
            else if (count == 3) a[i][j] = 1;   
        }


    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that  the issue might be in the line `#include <omp.h>`. Some  libraries may require you to include their header files in a certain order, or else they can result in [errors like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569538/compilation-error-whith-boost-python-and-lapack). My suggestion is to try placing that #include at the top of the file. However, it does not appear that it is being used, so I would leave it out until you determine that you need it.

In addition, even if you remove that #include, you will  need to make sure to `#include <time.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`, or else your calls to `time()` and `rand()` will result in compilation errors.

Comment: I removed the <omp.h> and added <stdlib.h>, but i get the same error. project.c:50:31: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
 }                             }

Comment: I am getting no such error. You say the error is on line 50, column 31? It looks like that's where you have a nested for loop. I don't know why your compiler would complain, since the syntax looks valid, and it compiles for me. What compiler are you using? Are you sure you  are compiling your latest code? Also, what happens when you add curly braces after the for loop and put `printf("%d",a[i][j]);` inside of them? It's worth adding curly braces after all of your if statements and for loops - it makes your code much more readable.

Comment: @Katya: As far as I can tell, there is no column 31 on line 50. Please provide more accurate code and error messages.